# How to change the characters used for empty space in Vim status line?

Tags: vim

I’m using the following `statusline` setting in Vim:

```
set statusline=%<%f\ %h%m%r%{fugitive#statusline()}%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
```

It produces the following status line:

[image: Status line screenshot]

Comment: Do you have this issue in Vim, GVim, or both?  Does the problem appear if Vim is run as `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: Just mvim actually. Vim works fine in both mac and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Had the same issue, and eventually realized that I was seeing it only when using certain colorschemes. A little more digging revealed that these colorschemes were setting `StatusLine` and `StatusLineNC` highlighting groups to identical values.

`:help StatusLineNC` notes that if `StatusLine` and `StatusLineNC` have equal values, then Vim will use `^^^` in the status line of the current window.

The fix was to comment out the lines that changed these values in the problematic colorschemes.

Comment: Great finding!  This answer should be accepted as it reveals the actual reason of the little-known behavior.  (By the way, welcome to StackOverflow, and keep up the good work!)

Comment: Awesome! I was using `railscasts.vim` and the values were equal for `StatusLine` and `StatuslineNC`. I changed them and it looks much cleaner now. thanks!

Comment: thank you so much for this! i have been messing around w/ fillchar for an hour and it was my color scheme :S

Answer (score 3):

The `fillchars` option specifies the characters to fill status lines
and vertical separators. The `stl:` and `stlnc:` items in the option’s
value correspond to the status line of the current window and the
status lines of the other windows, respectively. See the current state
of the `fillchars` option (by `:set fcs?`), and try to set the filling
characters for statusline explicitly:

```
:set fillchars+=stl:\ ,stlnc:\ "
```

(Here the last quote symbol starts a comment and does not affect the
value set, it was added only to make preceding space noticeable.)

Comment: Running `set fcs?` produces `fillchars=vert:|,fold:-,stl: ,stlnc:`, however `:set fillchars+=stl:\ ,stlnc:\ "` has no effect. I played with changing the command, but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

standard statusline is `:set statusline=%<%f\ %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P` so I guess it's the fugitive-part that is causing this. What does it do? and in what format does it display data?

from `:help 'statusline'`:

```
{ NF  Evaluate expression between '%{' and '}' and substitute result.
          Note that there is no '%' before the closing '}'.
```

You're statusline looks correct so have a look at the `fugitive` part...

---

**UPDATE**

Did a `git clone http://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive` and tried the statusline above
which can be found in the [documentation for fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/master/doc/fugitive.txt) and the statusline is correctly
displayed for me. Using xbuntu 11.04. So update to the latest and try again is my advice.
and use `set ruler`

Comment: It works fine for me in Ubuntu as well and vim in OS, its macvim that's giving the trouble.